# pandas dataframe match column from external file

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I have a df with

```
col0 col1 col2 col3
a    1    2    text1
b    1    2    text2
c    1    3    text3
```

and i another text file with

```
col0 col1 col2
met1 a    text1
met2 b    text2
met3 c    text3
```

how do i match row values from col3 in my first df to the text file col2 and add to previous df only col0 string with out changing the structure of the df

desired output:

```
col0 col1 col2 col3  col4
a    1    2    text1 met1
b    1    2    text2 met2
c    1    3    text3 met3
```

Comment: Where does met3 in col4 come from?

Comment: Hi @ScottBoston edited the post, just head 3 lines of the df and the file, i have almost 200,000 lines in my df and almost the same amount of lines in the text file, apologies for improper edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print(df)
  col0  col1  col2   col3
0    a     1     2  text1
1    b     1     2  text2
2    c     1     3  text3

print(df2)
   col0 col1   col2
0  met1    a  text1
1  met2    b  text2
2  met3    c  text3
```

Merge df and df2

```
df3 = df.merge(df2, left_on='col3', right_on='col2',suffixes=('','_1'))
```

Housekeeping... renaming columns etc...

```
df3 = df3.rename(columns={'col0_1':'col4'}).drop(['col1_1','col2_1'], axis=1)

print(df3)

  col0  col1  col2   col3  col4
0    a     1     2  text1  met1
1    b     1     2  text2  met2
2    c     1     3  text3  met3
```

And, reassign to df if you wish.

```
df = df3
```

---

OR

`df = df.assign(col4=df.merge(df2, left_on='col3', right_on='col2',suffixes=('','_1'))['col0_1'])`

```
print(df)
  col0  col1  col2   col3  col4
0    a     1     2  text1  met1
1    b     1     2  text2  met2
2    c     1     3  text3  met3
```

Comment: I did not understand the second block of code after or

Comment: df.assign creates a new column in that dataframe and "assigns" those values.   After the equals sign is a merge where at the end I only select one column 'col0_1' (the 'met's) column and "assign" it back to the new column in df, name col4.  [df.assign](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html#pandas-dataframe-assign)

Comment: I get more rows after the merge is it because the df1 has say 100 rows and df2 has 200 or vice versa does the length of the column matter?

Comment: Yes, that is possible due to cartesian products caused with many to one or many to many joins possibilities.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `pandas.dataframe.merge()`. E.g.:

```
df.merge(df2.loc[:, ['col0', 'col2']], left_on='col3', right_on='col2')
```

Answer (score 1):

Call your df `df1`. Then first load the text file into a dataframe using `df2 = pd.read_csv('filename.txt')`. Now, you want to rename the columns in `df2` so that the column on which you want to merge has the same name in both columns:

```
df2.columns = ['new_col1', 'new_col2', 'col3']
```

Then:

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, on='col3')
```

Comment: will this add a new column to my df1?

Comment: this will create a new merged dataframe.

Comment: sorry will that change the structure of my original df?

Comment: This works, but actually the solution of @thn works just as well and is more elegant.